# SSL on Google App Engine for services/modules on a custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, dns

with a Google App Engine java project using 2 different services/modules (default and api) and using a custom domain, how can I use GAE SSL support for both services/modules?

with appspot.com domain, I can use:

- https://myproj.appspot.com (default)
- https://api-dot-myproj.appspot.com

however when adding a *custom domain* 'beta.mydomain.com' through App Engine / Settings 
(adding a custom domain name of beta.mydomain.com, and configuring my dns so that *.beta.mydomain.com and beta.mydomain.com CNAME to ghs.googlehosted.com)

- https://beta.mydomain.com works fine
- https://api.beta.mydomain.com ***doesn't work***

how can I protect both urls using GAE https?

thanks

Comment: Did you read the docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl for getting the managed SSL set up for a custom domain?

Comment: as mentioned I'm using the java version, so I read the equivalent for Java... still didn't help.